# How to check if an item returned is a list itself?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Morning -

I'm trying to see if there is a way to check if an item returned from a list is a list itself.

For example

```
(elt '(a (b c) d) 1)
```

Is there a way to check that the item returned is a list?

I tried using length,

```
(length (elt '(a (b c) d) 1))
```

but if it is given an item that is not a list it throws an error.

In short I'm looking for a way to go through each element of a list and check if it is a list or not.

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the listp tells you that :

```
(listp (elt '(a (b c) d) 1))
```

Comment: The sad thing is that I have been using integerp for a bit.. -1 myself for overlooking the obvious.

Comment: Nice, I like that `listp` in CL in O(1), since dotted and circular lists are considered lists too. In the Scheme world, `list?` only returns true for proper lists, so (other than implementations with immutable conses, like Racket), `list?` is O(n), which means that usually I'm hesitant to suggest the use of `list?` for general use.