# Using listp to test for list, but (listp nil) returns true

Tags: common-lisp

On GNU Clisp 2.49, `(listp nil)` returns true.  Could someone explain?  Searching found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512143/how-to-check-if-an-item-returned-is-a-list-itself/12512301#12512301) with an answer that indicated that the expression should be returning NIL.

Comment: Note that if you try to evaluate '() it evaluates to nil

Comment: @Luis Alves: not only that, it is actually the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Common Lisp [listp](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/f_listp.htm) returns `T` for a list. `nil` is the empty list, so `(listp nil)` is `T`. `NIL` can also be written as `()`.

```
CL-USER 38 > (eq (read-from-string "()")
                 (read-from-string "NIL"))
T
```

In Common Lisp `nil` has multiple purposes: the symbol named `NIL` in the `COMMON-LISP` package, **the empty list**, the boolean (or generalized boolean) representing false, and the name of the empty type.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected as much--just as the empty set is still a set.  So, is there a predicate commonly used to test whether an element of a list is itself a list?

Comment: @user559840: how about `listp`?

Comment: `consp` is the operator for which I was looking.

Comment: @user559840 But `consp` only checks for things that are conses.  It returns true on all lists except for a very important list:  `nil`.  The answer to "Is there a predicate commonly used to test whether an element of a list is itself a list?" is "yes, it's **listp**".